# How to print together elements from two different MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have these two tables in MySQL. One is called 'History' and one is called 'Annotated'.

The 'History' table is full of random YouTube video id's that can be repeated. The 'Annotated' table contains a unique copy of each video id along with a description of that id. Looks something like this:

```
 History                            Annotated

 videoid                    videoid          description

 videoid_1                  videoid_1        descript_1
 videoid_1                  videoid_2        descript_2
 videoid_3                  videoid_3        descript_3
 videoid_2                  etc.             etc.
 videoid_3
 videoid_1
 etc.
```

I'm trying to print out a specific set of video id's from the History table, duplicates and all. That is quite simple. The problem is I need to print their description beside them.

So I have an array of the History video id's I want to print and I'm trying to write a MySQL command that will print the corresponding descriptions beside them but it's not working properly. Here's what I have so far:

```
$implodedIdVideo = the array of specific history video id's, imploded for MySQL

SELECT History.videoid, Annotated.description 
FROM History, Annotated 
WHERE History.videoid = Annotated.videoid 
AND History.videoid IN ($implodedIdVideo)
ORDER BY History.videoid DESC";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $row['videoid']. " : ". $row['description'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

This above MySQL command works but its supposed to give me like 10 results but I'm getting like 50 and I have no idea why. I'm hoping if someone understands what I'm trying to do, they'll be able to recognize what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: videoid is not unique? If they are supposed to repeat, do a DISTINCT

Comment: When you say you expect 10 results but get 50, are you expecting 10 because there are 10 rows in History? Or are there 10 unique rows in History?

Comment: @ohr videoid is unique in Annotated but NOT unique in History

Comment: @Mike The History table contains EVERYONE's history. The array I create is one person's history, duplicates and all, and for this one person there are 10 videos. No idea why I'm getting fifty; my SQL is wrong somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have duplicates in your History table, so the server return a description for each one. Try adding GROUP BY History.videoid before the ORDER.

Complete query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    History.videoid, Annotated.description 
FROM 
    History, Annotated 
WHERE 
    History.videoid = Annotated.videoid 
AND 
    History.videoid IN ($implodedIdVideo)
GROUP BY 
    History.videoid
ORDER BY 
    History.videoid DESC";
```

Comment: Wow, that worked!!! My head is too melted right now to process what happened, but thanks! There's just one thing missing and that's for some reason this query isn't printing the duplicate video id's that are contained in the $implodedIdVideo?

Comment: @AzzyDude: Can you reformulate the question? I'm unable to understand what are you trying to ask.. (Sorry, but my native language is not English.)

Answer (score 0):

Given your `History` table, it appears you've got some almost-duplicate records: `videoid_1` v.s. `Videoid_1`. Note the `V` vs. `v`.

MySQL's string comparison are by default case-insensitive, so when you do your join in the query, the `History.Videoid_1` value will match `Annotated.videoid_1` AND `Annotaded.Videoid_1`, essentially duplicating your results.

If you really do intend to have those mixed-case identifiers, you'll want to force a binary comparison, which makes it case sensitive:

```
WHERE BINARY History.videoid = Annotated.videoid 
      ^^^^^^
```

or switch your two tables to a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting multiple rows for each videoid because you have multiple rows for each videoid in History. The thing is though, you do not appear to require any information from History in your query. You could just query Annotated without joining to any other tables, so I am not sure why you joined History. The only effect it has is the one you observe, that rows are duplicated.

Comment: I need the History table because the precise order of the id's are imperative. I can print the order fine, it looks like: id_1, id_1, id_2, id_3, id_1 but I need to print the description beside each one. If I query Annotated, I'll just get a list of unique descriptions out of order

Comment: Your ORDER BY clause specifies ordering by videoid, which is a column present in Annotated. The order should show up as id_1, id_1, id_1, id_2, id_3, not the order you said.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's wrong, I want the order to be like id_1, id_1, id_2, id_3, id_1 but I'm not sure hot to maintain that order

Comment: Evidently you require another column to use in the ORDER BY clause.